# Spring Security - Ajax calls ignoring @ExceptionHandler

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I have a controller in my project that handles all exceptions defined like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlingController {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(value = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity accessDeniedException() {
        Logger.getLogger("#").log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception caught!");
        return new ResponseEntity("Access is denied", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

I'm focusing on one specific exception here and that is AccessDeniedException that is thrown by Spring Security on unauthorized requests. This is working properly for "normal" aka non-ajax requests. I can click on a link or enter URL directly in the location bar and I will see this message if request is unauthorized.

However on AJAX request (using Angular for it) I'm getting standard 403 error page as a response but what's interesting is that I can see that AccessDeniedException is caught by this controller!

I did some research and it seems that I need to have custom AccessDeniedHandler so I made this:

Added this lines in my Spring Security configuration:

```
.and()
.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/error/403/");
```

and I made special controller just to handle this:

```
@Controller
public class AjaxErrorController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/error/403/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity accessDeniedException() {
        return new ResponseEntity("Access is denied (AJAX)", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

}
```

Now this is working fine but the exception is still caught in the first controller but return value of that method is getting ignored. Why?

Is this how it's supposed to be done? I have a feeling that I am missing something here.

I'm using Spring 4.2.5 with Spring Security 4.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know all the details, my theory is that it can be a content type issue.

Often when doing AJAX requests, the response is expected to be in JSON, so the browser will add an `Accept: application/json` header to the request.

Your response entity on the other hand:

```java
new ResponseEntity("Access is denied", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
```

is a text response, the default Content-Type of this with a typical Spring setup is `text/plain`.

When Spring detects that it can't deliver a response with type the client wants, it fallbacks to the default error page.